# Error when trying to display page in JSON format

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this error when trying to display page in JSON format but with the html format it works fine

**An exception occurred while executing**

```
 &#039;SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.libProjet AS libProjet2, t0.site AS site3, t0.partceg AS partceg4, t0.datego AS datego5, t0.dateResmisOff AS dateResmisOff6, t0.dateTransfert AS dateTransfert7, t0.nompays_id AS nompays_id8, t0.libTypeProj_id AS libTypeProj_id9, t0.nomclt_id AS nomclt_id10,t0.libContrat_id AS libContrat_id11, t0.libEtatProj_id AS libEtatProj_id12, t0.libEtatOff_id AS libEtatOff_id13
```

FROM projet t0 WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE t0.id = ?' with params ["index.json"]:

this is the entity

```
class projet
{
/**
* @var integer 
*
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
private $id;

/**
* @var string
*
* @ORM\Column(name="libProjet", type="string", length=255)
*/
private $libProjet;

/**
* @var string
*
* @ORM\Column(name="site", type="string", length=255)
*/
private $site;

/**
* @var float
*
* @ORM\Column(name="partceg", type="float")
*/
private $partceg;

//....
```

This is the Controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$entities = $em->getRepository('rexBundle:projet')->findAll();

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('rexBundle:projet');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t')

->select('t.id','t.libProjet','t.site','t.partceg',
'IDENTITY(t.nompays) AS nompays',
'IDENTITY(t.libTypeProj) AS libTypeProj',
'IDENTITY(t.nomclt) AS nomclt',
'IDENTITY(t.libContrat) AS libContrat',
'IDENTITY(t.libEtatProj) AS libEtatProj',
'IDENTITY(t.libEtatOff) AS libEtatOff',
't.datego',
't.dateResmisOff',
't.dateTransfert')

 ->getQuery();
 $entities = $query->getResult();

 $entity = new projet();
 $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

 return array(
 'entities' => $entities,
 'entity' => $entity,
 'form' => $form->createView(),
);
}
```

Comment: Show us the controller that send the response

Comment: I have added the controller in the question

Comment: Where you send the json response? That controller is to show a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want send JSON response, read this article in documentation.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response

Now in your controller you don't send JSON Response, you only render form

Example how send JSON response:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$response = new Response();
$response->setContent(json_encode(array(
    'data' => 123,
)));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```